# deleting rows after the last occurence of a value in each group

Tags: r

I am trying to clean my data in R (cc. 1M rows).
For each E(ntity) I would like to delete rows that come after the last occurrence of 1 in the V(alue) column. Rows are ordered by E and A(ttribute).
What would be an effective way to do this?

Example:

From this

```
E = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3) 
A = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5) 
V = c(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0)
df = data.frame(E,A,V)
df
```

I would like to create this

```
E = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3) 
A = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3) 
V = c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1)
df = data.frame(E,A,V)
df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)   
setDT(df)[, .SD[seq_len(max(which(V==1)))], by = E]
#   E A V
#1: 1 1 1
#2: 1 2 0
#3: 1 3 1
#4: 2 1 0
#5: 2 2 0
#6: 2 3 1
#7: 3 1 1
#8: 3 2 1
#9: 3 3 1
```

Or another option would be to use `head` (from @Procrastinatus Maximus comments)

```
setDT(df)[, head(.SD, max(which(V==1))), by = E]
```

Or we can use `.I`

```
setDT(df)[df[, .I[seq_len(max(which(V==1)))], by = E]$V1]
```

Comment: or: `setDT(df)[, head(.SD, max(which(V==1))), by = E]`

Comment: I went with setDT(df)[, head(.SD, max(which(V==1))), by = E] as it could handle cases with all 0 -s

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(E) %>% slice(1:max(which(V == 1)))
```